# Sharepoint Profile field mapped to AD field

Tags: active-directory

I'm have the telephoneField on my Active Directory and it's mapped to a Sharepoint Profile  field. It's reading the data from the AD just fine, the thing is that the user can change the phone number and i need this change to go to the AD too. I tried to create a Export mapping from the Profile to the AD but it won't let me.

I can't have a import and export mapping on the same field, or after i do a import, i delete this map and create the export one?

hope i'm clear enough.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have import and export configured for the same field. You could try to change to Export once you have imported.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i'm going to do. Seems the logical way to do it correctly